# Attempt to get guild member always errors

Tags: javascript

So I'm creating a third-party to discord verification bot, and all of it works, except for when I try to access the guild member. The third-party sends all the data back to the bot, but for some reason, (and all the information is correct), it doesn't allow me to get the guild member, (via their discord id), and change their nickname.

Here's the code, and any help is appreciated!

```
let Mem = message.guild.members.cache.find(Member => Member.id === String(message.content.split(' ')[0]));

Mem.setNickname(message.content.split(' ')[1]);
```

I've tried (what I think) is all of the ways to access the guild member, but none of them work. The id is valid, which is why it's even more confusing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to access the whole server list by default. You need discord `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent, and also make sure to enable `Server Members Intent` in the website `Discord Developer > Your Bot > Bot > Privileged Gateway Intents > Server Members Intent`

Comment: So it still doesn't work, and the only error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNickname' of undefined."

Comment: Try logging members.cache into the console

Comment: It outputs nothing.